# c# parse to json format

Tags: c#, json, excel

i'm trying to get data from excel sheets and to copy it to a txt file. I Succeed getting the data but the only problem is how to parse it in this format (json format):

```
{
    "First sheet": {
        "A": {
            "1": "The content of A1",
            "3": "The content of A3"
        },
        "B": {
            "1": "The content of B1",
            "2": "The content of B2",
            "7": "The content of B7"
        },
        "C": {
            "1": "The content of C1",
            "2": "The content of C2",
            "7": "The content of C7"
        },
        "AA": {
            "98": "The content of AA98"
        }
    },
    "2nd sheet": {
        "D": {
            "4": "Content of D4 in 2nd sheet",
            "6": "56",
            "7": "2.3"
        }
    }
}
```

I mean, how do i create objects in this Hierarchy? (object inside an object inside an object...):

```
"First sheet": {
    "A": {
        "1": "The content of A1",
```

p.s: I tried creating objects and parse them with:
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(sheets[0])

Comment: Are you getting the data in list of objects or datatable??

Comment: I would like to know the format of graph you want serialize to json, btw where is your code? we need to know the format of sheets

Comment: Did you define this format your self and are you able to adjust it? If that is the case I would adwise you to drop the dictionary structure and using a List structure since dictionarys don't have any ordering which is weird for this application.

Answer (score 0):

you can check here http://json2csharp.com/ it's generate class for json it's not perfect most of the times but usually it will help alot.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called Serializing/Formatting. Parse is taking string and putting it in a stucture.

Define these classes:

```
public class Root : SortedDictionary<string, Sheet>
{
}
public class Sheet : SortedDictionary<string, Row>
{
}
public class Row : SortedDictionary<string, string>
{
}
```

Install the nuget package newtonsoft.json

Then you are able to do:

```
Root myRoot;
//copy data to myRoot
string serialized = JsonConvert.Serialize(myRoot);
```

The only problem is that they will be sorted according to the key and not in the order of the file which my or may not be acceptable to you.

Comment: revert the process, OP want to serialize in JSON his graph

Answer (score 0):

### List item

While I am sure that there is at least one library that could help you do this, you could easily do this yourself if you are reading the spreadsheet data from left-right and top-down. If so, I suggest the use of Dictionary objects with something like the following logic:

1. Instantiate a Dictionary to hold the sheet info.
2. For each sheet, do the following:

   **a.** Instantiate a Dictionary to hold the row info.

   **b.** For each row, do the following:

   1. Instantiate a Dictionary to hold the column info.
   2. For each column that has a value, add a value to the column info dictionary with the column number as the key.
   3. Add the column info dictionary to the row dictionary using the row letter as the key.

   **c.** Add the row info dictionary to the sheet info dictionary with the sheet name as the key.

Serializing the sheet dictionary should give you the result you wish.